# conflicting perl blocks in separate virtual hosts

Tags: apache, virtualhost, httpd.conf, mod-perl

I am hosting a test site through a VirtualHost on my local machine. I sometimes have the need to test changes I made against a version of site before changes, just to see the differences in behaviour. At first I thought this would be as simple as configuring 2 VirtualHost blocks, one with the DocumentRoot set to /mysite_new and the other VirtualHost with a DocumentRoot set to  /mysite_original... and for the most part, this works. I set the ServerName different on each and set my host file to point to the same IP address for each hostname.

The problem arises with the  block that I have in the VirtualHost block(s):

In the first:

```
<Perl>
    use '/mysite_new/lib';   
</Perl>
```

In the second:

```
<Perl>
    use '/mysite_original/lib';   
</Perl>
```

At first I thought these would be exclusive to whichever virtual host was serving, so they would us their own versions of perl modules within libs, but after investigating a little on how mod_perl works it seems that the statements are just executed when the config is read on startup and the latter one will simply displace the former (presumably because use unshifts onto the @INC array, and therefore matches those modules /mysite_orig/lib before /mysite_new/lib?).

My question then is, is there a way to use different lib locations depending on which virtual host is serving?

Answer (score 0):

No. There isn't. You can use separate Apache instances with different configuration files.